# What's the difference between "очень приятно" and "приятно познакомиться"?

Tags: выбор-слова

On some site I was on months ago (I can't recall), it says that "очень приятно" is "nice to meet you" and I've heard a native Russian use that phrase. But, I've also used the Nemo app a bit and it says that "приятно познакомиться" is "nice to meet you"
Are they the same? Does it matter? Is there a formality difference?

Comment: It's obvious but I meantion it nevertheless: "очень приятно" means "(I am) very pleased" and can be used in many other situations.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in a colloquial speech both forms are interchangeable, [`очень приятно`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE)  is just a shortened form for "очень приятно познакомиться" and it's completely acceptable to say whenever and whosever hand you shake the very first time.